# Loop through json result and sort in numeric order

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my json:

```
{"event": { 
"items": [
            {"position": "2", "name": "John Doe 1"},
            {"position" : "1", "name": "John Doe 2"},
            {"position": "3", "name": "John Does 3"}
            ]
        }
```

This is how I loop through results after reading the json result:

```
$.each(data.event.items, function(val) {
 $('#list').append('<li>'+data.event.items[val].name+'</li>');
});
```

Right now the order is: John Doe 1, John Doe 2, John Doe 3. I want to loop them and display them in order of the position that is has been given. So the correct order would be John Doe 2, John Doe 1, John Doe 3.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can sort your items before building the display :

```
data.event.items.sort(function(a,b) {
   return a.position-b.position;        
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/omigil/1/edit) (click "Run with JS")

Please note that there is no [JSON](http://www.json.org/) in your problem, `data` is a plain JavaScript object.

Comment: Thank you, that was an easy answer, I wounder I didn't think about something like that myself. And I simplified my code for the question, it is JSON...

Answer (score 4):

You will need to sort the items first:

```
data.event.items.sort(function(item_a, item_b) {
    return item_a.position - item_b.position;
});
```